# Scope of Integration Testing in a CI CD workflow

Tags: web-services, continuous-integration, tdd, integration-testing, continuous-deployment

The question is more about the fundamental understanding of a normal/ideal CI flow and understanding the scope of integration testing in it.

As per my understanding, the basic CI CD flow is

```
UnitTesting --> IntegrationTesting --> Build Artifact --> Deploy to Dev/Sandbox or any other subsequent environments.
```

So unit tetsing and integration testing collectively decide/make sure if the build is stable and ready to be deployed.

But, recently, we had this discussion in my team where we wanted to run integration tests on deployed instances on Dev/Sandbox etc , so as to verify if the application is working fine after deployment.

And the [microsoft's article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191495.aspx) on Build - Deploy - Test workflows suggests that this could be a possible way.

So , my questions are :-

1. Are integration tests supposed to test configuration of different environments ?
2. Are integration tests supposed to be run before packaging application or deploying the application ?
3. If at all, some automated testing is required to test deployed application functioning on all environments ?
   If not integration tests then what could be alternative solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing *Integration* testing with [*System* testing](http://www.softwaretestingclass.com/difference-between-system-testing-vs-integration-testing/).

Integration testing checks that *some* components can work together (can be integrated). You may have integration tests to verify how does the Data layer API operates with a database; or how does the the Web API responds to HTTP calls. You might not have the entire system completely working in order to do integration testing of its components.

Unlike integration tests, the System tests require all the components to be implemented and configured. That is end-to-end testing (e.g. from a web request to a database record). This kind of testing requires the entire system to be deployed which makes them more 'real' but expensive.

Comment: in your view how effective is to do System Testing. Is it even required ? As these connections, web request can be checked at the start up of the app. Is there a real need for separate System Tests ??

Comment: Yest, it is. For instance, the entire System _might_ consists of numerous components (developed by different teams). You may test your components in isolation but that will not guarantee that _your_ component won't be broken by one of the _other_ components.